# Replace a exact string using Regex in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Consider the the following text

> The capital asset as defined in section 2(14) is an exhaustive definition which encompasses all properties of any kind with certain exceptions but the key word is that the property should be "held" section 2.

Now I want to find **section 2**, for the same I have written the following Regex:

```
/\bsection+\.*\s+2\b/i
```

But it is also matching **section 2** of **section 2(14)**. I just want it to only match the exact text, not the part of text which is matching with the *regex*. I know I need to modify the regex, but what are the changes required?

Comment: That's one example, but can you describe in words generally what you want your regex to match and what you don't want it to match? What characterizes the "section 2" in "section 2(14)" versus "section 2." at the end that indicates it should not be matched?

Comment: @lurker It matching section 2 from section 2(14), it should not match section from section 2(14)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. By *why*? What is it about "section 2(14)" that makes you not want to match it? You need to have some specification/rule you can describe for matching in order to devise a regex.

Comment: So, you want it to match anything that contains the search string, and is followed only by a space or a dot?

Comment: @lurker yes, I don't want to match it in section 2(14)

Comment: I'm sorry, still not clear to me. I know you don't want to match "section 2" in "section 2(14)". It's unclear what rule for matching, though, you are trying to establish. Is it because it has `(` after the `2` instead of something else? Or because it's not the *last* "section 2" in the line? Or something else?

Comment: Try [`\bsection+\.*\s+2\b(?![()])`](https://regex101.com/r/bF5oL1/3). Here, you will match the `2`not followed by a word character and `(` and `)`. You can add more blacklisted characters to the character class. Or, use a whitelist approach with `\bsection+\.*\s+2\b(?=[\s.])`.

Comment: @lurker I need to hyperlink section 2, so it also hyper linking section 2 in string section 2(14), section 2 and section 2(14) are different, an the text will come anywhere in the text

Comment: @lurker the above expression works for section 2, now I want to make generalised expression, I mean the input could be section 2 or section 3(12), it should match the whole string , it should not find in part of any string

Comment: @DeeptiKakade: Did you address me? To match any digit, you may use `\d`. To match section 3, use `/\bsection+\.*\s+\d+\b(?=[ .,;!?])/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `\bsection+\.*\s+2([ .,;?|!])/i` . This will only match with `section 2` if it is followed by a space or a punctuation mark different than `(`.

Comment: `[ |.|,|;|?|!]` = `[ .,;?|!]`. Character classes are not groups.

Answer (score 0):

/\bsection+.*\s+2\b([[:punct:]]|\s/

basically you would want the word to end with whitespace or a punctuation.